# determining the path to a mbean for navigating to it

Tags: wlst

is there some way (other than the recording using admin console) to find the Path to a mbean in the namespace in order to navigate to it using cd() wlst command.

Eg)

connect(adminUserName, adminPassword, adminURL)

serverConfig()

authenticatorPath= '/SecurityConfiguration/' + domainName + '/Realms/' + realmName + '/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultAuthenticator'

print authenticatorPath

```
cd(authenticatorPath)
```

how to determine the path to be used for the navigation

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the lookup() command given in WLST. You must know the type of the MBean that should be as second argument.

Ref: [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1181613)